# Ionic 2 or angular 2 Email & password validations at html page level

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm trying to add patterns for Email/Phonenumber and Password. Some how pattern is not working as expected.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #signInForm="ngForm">
          <ion-list padding-bottom>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Email/Phone number" required #name="ngModel"
                         [(ngModel)]="email" pattern="^(?!^[.])([-'a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\.)*[-'a-zA-Z0-9_]+@(?!\\.+)([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$""></ion-input>
              <div [hidden]="email.valid"
                   class="alert alert-danger">
                Email is required and Email or Phone number pattern is wrong.
              </div>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-input type="password" id="password"
                         required
                         [(ngModel)]="password" name="password"
                         #name="ngModel" placeholder="Password" pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&])(?=.{8,})">
                <div [hidden]="password.valid"
                     class="alert alert-danger">
                  Password is required and must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters.
                </div>
              </ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <p float-right (click)="forget()">Forget Password?</p>
            <button ion-button color="secondary" [disabled]="!signInForm.form.valid" round (click)="login()" float-left>Proceed</button>
          </ion-list>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ion-input](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/) does not have `pattern` property, so i am not sure if it shoudl work.

I would recommend you to go with reactive forms way.

In component define your form

```
  public loginForm = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(?!^[.])([-'a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\.)*[-'a-zA-Z0-9_]+@(?!\\.+)([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/)]),
    password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
  });
```

Modify template (add formGroup and formControlName)

```
<ion-list [formGroup]="loginForm">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>{{ 'login.email' | translate }}</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" formControlName="username"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>{{ 'login.password' | translate }}</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Now you can access your form values in component like

```
this.loginForm.value
```

or you can check if form is valid

```
this.loginForm.valid
```